# Update table based on the condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update the staging table based on the type if ZMD2 is present then update the records else update PNTP records.

[image]

```
UPDATE ITEMS_STAGING SET TYPE=b.TYPE,VALUE=b.VALUE
FROM ITEMS_STAGING a,ITEMS b
WHERE a.PARENT=b.PARENT
```

In the above statement I need to pick only ZMD2 records for the same parent if exists if not PNTP records. I tried to do UNION for the ITEMS it dint help.

Staging table Output:

[image]

Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: What does the first image represent? If the second image is the ITEMS_STAGING table and if you're **updating** it, it means that it already contains some data. Which data? In other words, either I didn't understand the question, or you didn't post everything you should have.

Comment: I need to update the ITEMS_STAGING table from ITEMS table. First table represents ITEMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use analytical function `row_number` which will group the rows by `parent` column to give them numbers and then we will take only one record from each group to update staging table using `merge` statement as following:

```
MERGE INTO ITEM_STAGING M
  USING (
   SELECT T.*, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.PARENT ORDER BY T.TYPE DESC) RN
     FROM ITEMS T
  ) 
  ON (M.PARENT = T.PARENT AND T.RN = 1)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET M.TYPE = T.TYPE AND M.VALUE = T.VALUE;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT IS.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TYPE DESC) RN
      FROM ITEMS_STAGING)
WHERE RN = 1;
```

I am not sure what you want to update in this table.